# Как реализованы такие штуки? Не знаю как объяснить, картинка в треде

Tags: css, html5

например вот здесь
http://demo.joomshaper.com/2014/onepage/
там где написано LATEST BLOG
видете, такие линии с кружочками идут вниз от каждого блока
уже не первый раз замечаю подобное но НИКАК не могу нагуглить не зная как это называется.

Comment: зачем гуглить? открывайте devtools и смотрите

Comment: кажется это vertical divider

Comment: timeline называется или по русскому шкала времени, вот к примеру : https://freefrontend.com/css-timelines/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

на коленке, думаю, что идею вы поняли

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.container__inner {
  width: 900px;
  position: relative;
}

.container__inner::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 2px;
  height: calc(100% - 60px); /* 60px = block's padding * 2 */
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-color: green;
}

.container__row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: -30px;
}

.container-block {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 30px;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.container-block::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: -7.5px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.container-block:last-of-type {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.container-block:last-of-type::after {
  left: -7.5px;
}

.container-block__inner {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container__inner">
    <div class="container__row">
      <div class="container-block">
        <div class="container-block__inner"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="container-block">
        <div class="container-block__inner"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container__row">
      <div class="container-block">
        <div class="container-block__inner"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="container-block">
        <div class="container-block__inner"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container__row">
      <div class="container-block">
        <div class="container-block__inner"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="container-block">
        <div class="container-block__inner"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```